# Ubuntu Server Install Old Version of Firefox

Tags: 12.04, server, firefox, downgrade

What is the best way to go back a version of Firefox on Ubuntu server. This is a server without a GUI so command line is the only thing that can be used.

Also once you install that old version how do you tell it's correct by version number?

For example, right now I get the following

```
$ /usr/bin/firefox --version
Mozilla Firefox 22.0
```

I want to go back to version 21.0 but when I install a different version that command no longer works.

The reason why I want to install the older version is Selenium tests don't work on the current version.

Here is an article I was following except I had to use `wget` instead of the GUI download tool: [How to Install Previous Versions of Firefox in Ubuntu 12.04](http://www.liberiangeek.net/2012/04/how-to-install-previous-versions-of-firefox-in-ubuntu-12-04-precise-pangolin/).